# Disk Cloning and Drive Partition Tags

Tags: partitioning, windows-8.1, disk-cloning, diskpart

I have cloned my single HDD to a new, larger disk but am having trouble matching the drive status tags.

The C: partition on the current drive is marked with the following tags: Boot, Page File, Crash Dump, Primary Partition
The Page File I can deal with and the Primary Partition is already present on the new drive's main partition so those aren't an issue. It's the others which concern me. Currently I'm using Windows 8.1

There is also a 100MB "System Reserved" partition which on the current drive is marked as: System, Active, Primary Partition.
Again, the Primary Partition tag is already on the new drive and I have marked the new partition as Active using the DiskPart tool from the command prompt.

How do I mirror the partition tags to ensure a smooth transition between the disks?

Comment: I think simplest way would be to use a cloning/immaging tool that can handle tags / flags as well. There are a lot of different cloning tools from Symantec, Acronis ....

Comment: If you cloned the HDD then the new HDD should be currently the exact same size as the old HDD and bootable.  More information on the cloning process would be required to help.

Comment: I have used the disk clone function provided in EaseUS Todo Backup Free 6.5. When this failed, I used the partition clone function.
I've used this tool several times before with no issue so I'm not sure what's happening this time.

Comment: First Issue resolved: The disk was set as a GPT one rather than a MBR one. Used right-click options on the relevant disk in Disk Management then 'Convert to MBR' option.